# new DecimalFormat(pattern) vs decimalFormat.applyPattern(pattern)?

Tags: java

I was working with DecimalFormat today and found a method inside it **applyPattern()** so whenever I had to use DecimalFormat or SimpleDateFormat I used to assign them as under:

```
private static final DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
```

But now I applied another approach. Instead of creating multiple static final Decimal or Date formats I created just one variable for each of them. And then applied them on the fly as under:

```
private static final DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat();
```

`private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();`

and whenever I need to apply a new pattern for any one of them I apply it like this:

```
dFormat.applyPattern(Constants.somePattern);
dFormat.format(SOMETHING);
```

So during a code review it was commented that this approach is not good for performance. But my point is that I am making my code more flexible as well as I am calling few **new's** so less objects are being created.

could someone throw some light on this point.

Comment: 99% of the time performance should not factor into this, pick whichever option is easiest to implement and understand (I'd argue that's always creating a new dateformat). I doubt you'll format numbers often enough for this to be your bottleneck.

Comment: Given that these types aren't thread-safe, I'd be very wary of having fields like this in either situation...

Comment: @JonSkeet So in case when I use threads. Then I should use the static final DecimalFormat format =  new DecimalFormat(pattern) approach?

Comment: No, then you should create a new `DecimalFormat` whenever you need one. Don't use a static field at all. (Alternatively, synchronize, or use one instance per thread.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok will take heed on this point in future. But will it not create more and more format objects. It's not about performance or memory, but is there any alternate approach so that I can minimize object creation, something like a cache.

Comment: [premature optimization is the source of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: "It's not about performance or memory" - if it's not about performance and memory, what *is* the problem with having a fair amount of object creation? Basically, these will be allocated and then garbage collected soon. I would generally favour a simple and safe approach over a complicated and potentially-more-efficient approach until you have *evidence* that it's making an unacceptable problem for performance.

Comment: Why do you want to optimize? does your application suffer from performance issues? if the answer is no - don't optimize, if it's yes, did you prove that this is your bottleneck? if no - use performance tools to analyze where is the bottleneck and fix it. I'd be very surprised to hear that this is your bottleneck.

Comment: Well I too prefer simple approaches. But same approaches are questioned and later rejected in code reviews. I too try to keep things simple and try to follow uncle Bob's advices.